# Push notification for development certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

How can I send push notifications to a build which is running under a development provisioning profile?

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 6):

You should use your development version of certificate to authenticate on Apple Push Notification Center.

For testing push-notifications you can use MacOs Application : [PushMeBaby](https://github.com/stefanhafeneger/PushMeBaby)

Full tutorial for using it can be found here : [(click me)](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services)

Answer (score 1):

For testing purpose you can use [urban airship](http://urbanairship.com/docs/push.html) and you can get the sample code also for iPhone application.

Answer (score 0):

For testing push-notification you can use http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/ I strongly recommend bryantan it works pretty faster.

You can test from both development and production But while testing from production please create the build using Adhoc.