# How to change the device token from NSData to NSString

Tags: ios, iphone

How to change the device token from NSData to NSString

```
  -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
    {
        //NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
        NSString *deviceTokenString= [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
        deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];


        NSLog(@"DeviceToken : %@", deviceToken);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceTokenString forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"isNotificationsEnabled"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }
```

Below is my output.

```
2015-01-09 11:33:22.096 SourceSage[3851:384928] DeviceToken : <cb26ce58 cc0f0229 bc1df7a2 68b4cdb5 ab6351c4 56fb4f8c 39958e8e 3f1f741a>
2015-01-09 11:33:22.109 SourceSage[3851:384928] DeviceToken : <cb26ce58 cc0f0229 bc1df7a2 68b4cdb5 ab6351c4 56fb4f8c 39958e8e 3f1f741a>
```

Comment: hope this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8798981/1866077

Comment: yes iam trying on it but the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving `NSData` to `NSUserDefaults`, you need to convert the `NSData` to `NSString` first and save that to the `NSUserDefaults`.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *token = [deviceToken description];
    token           = [token stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token           = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"DeviceToken : %@", token);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"isNotificationsEnabled"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

Comment: by using this iam getting error "use of undeclered identifier 'charlieSendData'

Comment: No iam not getting the same error is showing         2015-01-09 11:50:27.546 SourceSage[3896:388319] DeviceToken : <cb26ce58 cc0f0229 bc1df7a2 68b4cdb5 ab6351c4 56fb4f8c 39958e8e 3f1f741a>
2015-01-09 11:50:27.557 SourceSage[3896:388319] DeviceToken : <cb26ce58 cc0f0229 bc1df7a2 68b4cdb5 ab6351c4 56fb4f8c 39958e8e 3f1f741a>

Comment: yes but same the error is going

Comment: @NayeemuddinShaik: Instead of printing `deviceToken` print `deviceTokenString`. And what is the error now you are talking about ?

Comment: divice token is null iam getting

Comment: @NayeemuddinShaik: You can't test Push notification feature on Simulator, you need to use a device for that. In simulator deviceToken will be null

Comment: ya  iam testing in device its self  but it showing token is null plz help me

Comment: @NayeemuddinShaik: did you enabled push notification in the corresponding device ? Also did you enabled it on the provisioning profile ?

Comment: yes i done that,in old program witch i kept as a question? that working ,n it showing device token as nsdata but now it showing device token is null after taking ur code

Comment: same error  
   NSString *deviceTokenString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
   deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; NSLog(@"DeviceToken : %@", deviceTokenString);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceTokenString forKey:@"DeviceToken"];

Comment: DeviceToken : cb26ce58cc0f0229bc1df7a268b4cdb5ab6351c456fb4f8c39958e8e3f1f741a
2015-01-09 12:24:22.758 SourceSage[4027:398384] DeviceToken : cb26ce58cc0f0229bc1df7a268b4cdb5ab6351c456fb4f8c39958e8e3f1f741a

Comment: iam getting in NsDatat Formate again

Comment: @NayeemuddinShaik: That's not NSData, that's the device token (NSString)

Comment: DeviceToken : cb26ce58cc0f0229bc1df7a268b4cdb5ab6351c456fb4f8c39958e8e3f1f741a is this in Nsstring Formate??

Comment: thanq for helping @Midhun Mp thanqu so much