# how can we get device token for android for push notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push

i want to implement push notification in my application.i want to know,how we get the device token for push notification in android after enabling the google cloud messaging API.How can we get a device token for a particular device??

Comment: Did you check https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client?

Comment: Rajesh,these documentation provided by you based on about registration token id.actually i want to know about particular device token id for push notification

Answer (score 24):

```
try {
     InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);

     String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

}catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
}
```

Comment: in which part of project,we add these codes,and how we get the device token?

Comment: you can add above code in any Activity or Service. It's better to get token in Launcher Activity.And put your "SenderId" in R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId

Comment: but this code is working for registration token,actually i want the device token for particular android device.how can we get particular device token for android device

Comment: to integrate GCM in Android you only need "device token" which you get from above code and you have to send it to server.

Comment: InstanceID should be retrieved using `InstanceID.getInstance(context).getId();`