# how to get Device Token in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, devicetoken

I am working on push notifications. I wrote the following code for fetching a device token.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
        [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   
        NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");    
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
         return YES;
    }

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
    { 
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
        NSLog(@"This is device token%@", deviceToken);
    }

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
 { 
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
        NSLog(@"Error %@",err);    
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get device token for push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798725/get-device-token-for-push-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the latest code of swift 4.0, so you can use following code to get device token.

```
import UserNotifications

if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in
            }
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%.2hhx", $0) }.joined()

    }
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this code :

```
 // Register for Push Notification


 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings // NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
{
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{

    NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
    NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as you need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

}
```

Note : simulator not return deviceToken, deviceToken only return in device with valid APNS certificate

Comment: Your note I think is undervalued, I would highlight it since that solved a big issue of mine

Answer (score 2):

Enable "**Push Notifications**" in Xcode, this will fix the issue.

```
Targets -> Capabilities -> Push Notifications
```

[image: Attached image for reference]

> **Note:**
>   **Provisioning Profiles** Should be in **Active** State

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 and iOS 9 you need to register for notifications like this:

```
NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Note that if you also want to support iOS 7, then you'll need to call your existing code on the earlier versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened with me So You have to use following code to get device token:-

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
}
```

Even then it doesn't work Then please check your provisioning profile,it should be of that app ID by which you have created your ssl certificate for push notification.

Answer (score -1):

Get `device token` in **Swift 3**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg)
        .trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    print(token)
}
```