# Get registration ID for android for push notification using pushsharp

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I am using PushSharp library. I am able see deviceToken in the sample code https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Can anybody help me how to get that ? PushSharp sample code doesn't explain that

```
 apnsBroker.QueueNotification (new ApnsNotification {
DeviceToken = deviceToken,
Payload = JObject.Parse ("{\"aps\":{\"badge\":7}}")
```

Same for Android, How can I get the Registration ID's

```
 foreach (var regId in MY_REGISTRATION_IDS) {
 // Queue a notification to send
gcmBroker.QueueNotification (new GcmNotification {
RegistrationIds = new List<string> { 
    regId
},
Data = JObject.Parse ("{ \"somekey\" : \"somevalue\" }")
});
}
```

I am sending push notification via my service layer which is developed using webapi. Please suggest.

Comment: Hi Vicky. Noticed that this post actually existed before. I added in an answer. Next time, please avoid delete-reposting a question. Give some time for other users to see it and give opportunity for other new questions to be seen. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks AL. Yes. will follow that :)

Comment: The device token must be retrieved on the client end, then sent as a POST to your webapi, in order to do this you must use the device's native language or if you're wanting to use Javascript you'll have to use a lib like Cordova http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

The `deviceToken` (aka [Registration Token](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key)) is generated on the client app side.

For GCM - Android, to retrieve the registration token, you'll have to call [`InstanceID.getToken()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID.html#getToken(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). See the official documentation -- [Setup a GCM Client on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register):

For GCM - iOS, something similar needs to be done (with further settings needed to connect with APNs). See the official documentation -- [Setup a GCM Client on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client). The guide can be adjusted for Objective-C or Swift.

With that said, the code you referred to is under the section labeled *APNS Sample Usage*, so I guess it's also safe to refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8798725/4625829). Or directly from the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/CreateTokens/CreateTokens.html) if you plan to directly use APNs without GCM.

---

PS: If you intend to use GCM, I would strongly recommend that you proceed with using the newer version, which is [firebase-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-messaging). Official docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: Can you please tell me if I can use InstanceID.getToken() in javascript. Do you have any examples. I am using a Hybrid Cordova app.

Comment: @Vicky Nope. That was for Android. GCM does not have any support for Javascript, but the newer version (FCM) does. See the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token). Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks AL. Is it possible to implement FirebaseInstanceIdService in webapi.

Comment: @Vicky I'm not fully familiar with WebAPIs. I suggest looking around the FCM docs for more details. :)