# Xamarin iOS Push Notification stopped working in iOS 13

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, ios13

When I updated my iOS into version 13 suddenly the override method RegisteredForRemoteNotifications is not being called so no device token is being received for my phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get device token in iOS 13 with Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027344/how-to-get-device-token-in-ios-13-with-xamarin)

Comment: Hi , do you use `FireBase` to push notification ?

Comment: No @FreakyAll the registerforremotenotification is not being triggered so the request for device token is not happening at all

Comment: I used Firebase only for the android project @Junion jiang

Comment: @MarkJohnAlcantara Okey , not knowing the reason . Maybe you can check whether get access for the permission of notification In iOS 13.

Answer (score 0):

This solves my issues:

https://gist.github.com/ShravanJ/92e5c4254f4e991b01c83bb377cb22bf

Token structure changed for iOS 13