# Xamarin iOS build rejected by Apple EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Apple have rejected our latest build by saying its crashing, please see the log. But with Adhoc profile, it worked when in testing stage but somehow when we publish to app store, apple is saying they are not able to run this and is crashing. We've spent a day to understand what the issue could be but not sure how we read this log and fix the issue.

Here is the log from apple.

```
    {"app_name":"Compass.Mobile.iOS","timestamp":"2020-03-10 09:31:30.62 -0700","app_version":"6.8.0","slice_uuid":"11afa393-8480-30bd-8da8-e0c42b8445d2","adam_id":1451559446,"build_version":"335","bundleID":"---","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)","incident_id":"54C84CD3-FE19-4305-83C9-0066DBAFDBBE","name":"Compass.Mobile.iOS"}
Incident Identifier: 54C84CD3-FE19-4305-83C9-0066DBAFDBBE
CrashReporter Key:   3878f6ac3b11f4238a26d455e1bc4e2718c4bf35
Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
Process:             Compass.Mobile.iOS [3812]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/058EFEFD-7C9B-43A7-9152-3C779107ED9C/Compass.Mobile.iOS.app/Compass.Mobile.iOS
Identifier:          ----
Version:             335 (6.8.0)
AppStoreTools:       11C29
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           --- [2159]


Date/Time:           2020-03-10 09:31:29.3524 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-03-10 09:31:28.1610 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4367941632
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000104598000-00000001046f0000 [ 1376K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ss.Mobile.iOS

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_407  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001a1910b44 0x1a190b000 + 23364
1   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104608b90 0x104598000 + 461712
2   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104608cd8 0x104598000 + 462040
3   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104610950 0x104598000 + 493904
4   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104610f38 0x104598000 + 495416
5   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104610eb0 0x104598000 + 495280
6   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x000000010460e81c 0x104598000 + 485404
7   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x000000010460c460 0x104598000 + 476256
8   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x000000010460b118 0x104598000 + 471320
9   Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x000000010916943c 0x104598000 + 79500348
10  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x000000010915ea70 0x104598000 + 79456880
11  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x00000001047101c0 0x104598000 + 1540544
12  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x000000010472ac38 0x104598000 + 1649720
13  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104704c54 0x104598000 + 1494100
14  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x000000010470fb38 0x104598000 + 1538872
15  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104f9c034 0x104598000 + 10502196
16  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109b1c0f8 0x104598000 + 89669880
17  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109bda120 0x104598000 + 90448160
18  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109b0077c 0x104598000 + 89556860
19  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104fa11b0 0x104598000 + 10523056
20  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104cb0fb4 0x104598000 + 7442356
21  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104704a60 0x104598000 + 1493600
22  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104f9c034 0x104598000 + 10502196
23  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109b1c0f8 0x104598000 + 89669880
24  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109bda120 0x104598000 + 90448160
25  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109bdd9b0 0x104598000 + 90462640
26  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104617984 0x104598000 + 522628
27  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104617724 0x104598000 + 522020
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5d29298 0x1a52c8000 + 10883736
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a18aeb7c 0x1a18ad000 + 7036
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a18affd8 0x1a18ad000 + 12248
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a18bbcc8 0x1a18ad000 + 60616
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a1b85cc8 0x1a1ad8000 + 711880
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a1b80a24 0x1a1ad8000 + 690724
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a1b7ff40 0x1a1ad8000 + 687936
35  GraphicsServices                0x00000001abe10534 0x1abe0d000 + 13620
36  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5d0b580 0x1a52c8000 + 10761600
37  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x000000010743d390 0x104598000 + 48911248
38  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000106ba825c 0x104598000 + 39912028
39  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000106ba80e4 0x104598000 + 39911652
40  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104703dac 0x104598000 + 1490348
41  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000104f9c034 0x104598000 + 10502196
42  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109b1c0f8 0x104598000 + 89669880
43  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109bda120 0x104598000 + 90448160
44  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109be03dc 0x104598000 + 90473436
45  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109afa08c 0x104598000 + 89530508
46  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x0000000109cbcbd4 0x104598000 + 91376596
47  Compass.Mobile.iOS              0x00000001046f3414 0x104598000 + 1422356
48  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a19fee18 0x1a19fe000 + 3608

Thread 1 name:  tid_d03
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a191b9e0 0x1a1912000 + 39392
```

Comment: are you testing a RELEASE build?

Comment: This is a actually AppStore build. Adhoc build works just fine without any issue but when we create a build for app store and submit to apple for review, they are saying its crashing.

Comment: Symbolize the crash so you can see where in the code it is faulting (I would *assume* w/ the EXC_BAD_ACCESS it is a `null` pointer error)

Comment: you can make an AdHoc build in either Debug or Release, I am asking if you have actually tested with a RELEASE build

Comment: Hi, We figured it out basically it was due to push notifications device id changes on iOS 13. We didn't encounter it as their devices were already registered but apple faced it as they installed the build on a new device. Now looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027344/how-to-get-device-token-in-ios-13-with-xamarin to resolve the issue.

Comment: @SafeerAhmad Glad you found the solution . You mean the deviceToken is different with before , and need to modiy them .Right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right but the above fix is not working for me. How do I "Symbolize the crash"?