# Invalid Registration when sending Notification FCM specific device Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72781604/invalid-registration-fcm-in-api-using-entity-framework.) about getting an Invalid Registration FCM error. **I want to send notification to specific device through Backend .Net (EF)**

First of all I saved the deviceToken to the server (Xamarin iOS).

I read the error from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

> 200 + error:InvalidRegistration   Check the format of the registration
> token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration
> token the client app receives from registering with Firebase
> Notifications. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    //FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);

    //byte[] bytes = deviceToken.ToArray<byte>();
    //string[] hexArray = bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray();
    //DeviceToken = string.Join(string.Empty, hexArray);


    string deviceTokenString;
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
    {
        deviceTokenString = BitConverter.ToString(deviceToken.ToArray());
    }
    else
    {
        deviceTokenString = deviceToken.ToString();
    }

    Preferences.Set("TokenDevice", deviceTokenString);
}
```

I saved the **deviceToken** to **Preferences** and also saved it to the server. **My deviceToken code on Xamarin iOS:**

```
1A-F5-BE-DC-E4-22-07-46-AA-C4-87-CC-08-F5-D7-09-D4-AB-43-18-26-E0-65-3B-39-4E-6F-5E-02-35-9E-3A
```

I don't know if this method of getting the deviceToken on Xamarin iOS is really correct at this time?

**Backend I write API to send:**

```
private static Uri FireBasePushNotificationsURL = new Uri("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
private static string ServerKey = "key=AAAAqOId6Is:APxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....";

[HttpPost]
public async void PushNotificationToFCM(string deviceTokens, string title, string body, object data, string linkdirection)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var messageInformation = new Message()
        {
            notification = new NotificationFirebases()
            {
                title = title,
                text = body
            },
            data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "link", linkdirection },
            },
            to = deviceTokens
        };
        //Object to JSON STRUCTURE => using Newtonsoft.Json;
        string jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageInformation);

        string postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageInformation).ToString();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", ServerKey);

        var response = client.PostAsync(FireBasePushNotificationsURL, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        var responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}

public class Message
{
    public string to { get; set; }
    public NotificationFirebases notification { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }
}
public class NotificationFirebases
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

When I test I get the error:
`{\"multicast_id\":7343900550378569449,\"success\":0,\"failure\":1,\"canonical_ids\":0, \" results\":[{\"error\":\"InvalidRegistration\"}]}`. I have tried with deviceToken on Android and it succeeds. Appears only with deviceToken on Xamarin iOS

**Please note that I tried sending a notification in Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/.... then I got a notification, so you can see that my APNS configuration is not wrong.**

Looking forward to everyone's help. I also spent more than 2 weeks searching and trying to no avail. Thank you very much.

**Update Backend I write API to send:**

```
public void PushNotificationToFCM(string deviceTokens, string title, string body, object data, string linkdirection)
{
    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions() { 
        Credential= GoogleCredential.FromFile("private_key.json")
    });

    // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
    var registrationToken = deviceTokens;

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Apns = new ApnsConfig { Aps = new Aps { ContentAvailable = true, Sound = "default" } },
        Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "link", linkdirection },
        },
        Token = registrationToken,
        Notification= new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification()
        {
            Title = title,
            Body = body,
            
        }
    };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    string response = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).Result;
    // Response is a message ID string.
    Debug.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
}
```

I don't know if such iOS device's TokenDevice code is correct? I tried to submit it, however getting the error: `System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token)'`

I uninstalled and reinstalled the app, I got a new tokenDevice. However when I send the notification I still get the same error

Comment: Using `Backend .Net (EF)` is out of my scope, you can try below alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative workaround, you can use this NuGet package `Plugin.FirebasePushNotification`.

**1.** After Creating the iOS Project, add "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to your iOS Project and update the property to BundleResource.

**2.** In Info.plist and `FinishedLaunching method`, add following line:

```
 <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
  <false/>
```

```
     public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

**3.** Then add the below in App Construct.

```
 CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : {p.Token}");
            };
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
                foreach (var data in p.Data)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
                }

            };
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Opened");
                foreach (var data in p.Data)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
                }


            };
```

**4.** After getting the FCM registration token. then click Test, the targeted client device (with the app in the background) should receive the notification in the system notifications tray.

Comment: So is `p.Token` a tokenDevice that I can store it in the Database Server? And one more thing is that the Token Device code is only generated when running on the real device?

Comment: The `p.Token` is a `FCM registration token`. After you click Test, the targeted client device (with the app in the background) should receive the notification in the system notifications tray. You can refer to [this thread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message?authuser=0&hl=zh#retrieve-the-current-registration-token) for more details.

Comment: I will try it. And will respond here for you. Thank you so much