# Registering the iPhone application for push notification not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have tried out the example found in the link http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 ,  for my iPhone push notification message. I could successfully run all steps except the steps for registering the app for push notification for the first time.

I have followed different variations of the code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

But none worked for me. I am testing it in my iPhone 4 and my Xode version is 4.2 , OS is Lion.
Please advice.

Comment: What problem you are facing? did you go through this link : http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075255/push-notification-for-development-certificate/8075436#8075436

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Make sure your Xcode project is configured to use the explicit bundle ID from the provisioning portal
- Make sure you're not building the target with wildcard or team provisioning profile, check this on the project **AND** target settings
- If you created your provisioning profile before configuring the app ID for push, regenerate the provisioning profile

Also look at the error object in the UIApplicationDelegate method

```
application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
```

**EDIT 1**

Open your provisioning profile in a text editor and look for the string

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
```

If your profile does not contain this, it is not correctly set up for push.

Comment: 1) yes, I have the explicit bundle id   2) I am not using wild cards,  3) I have regenerated provision profile and tried to run the app again.

Comment: What error are you getting in the delegate method mentioned above?

Comment: Thank for your point, I have opened the file with extension .mobileprovision, It do not have the line "<key>aps-environment</key>", I think I have to redo the steps and check again.

Comment: I have recreated the provisioning profile and its working fine now.  As you told the problem was with this file. Thanks all.

Comment: Happy to hear it. If you find that this answer was the one that solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: In my case I was using the wildcard provisioning profile and that was the problem. Apple can be very complicated some times.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my workin code sample from application delegate (`AppDelegate.m`)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

To check if registration went OK, implement these three methods

```
– application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
– application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
– application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Or you can go to **Settings** to see if there is permissions settings available

like this:

[image: iPad Notification Settings]

Comment: I have added above 3 methods,  then I am getting the error in the console      "Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x143bc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}"                                                                But the app is running on iPhone with a blank white screen.      Also, I have not started the payload/php part of the code.

Comment: I have added NSlog printing for each method, I could get the output from the method     "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" only, and then the above error.

Comment: @Vinod great, now when you do have error response, you can find where the problem is. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681172/bundle-identifier-and-push-certificate-aps-environment-entitlement-error

Comment: Hi Marek, thanks for the link. This is my first app in Iphone. I have one question. I have created a CSR for my first Hello world app for the device. But at that time I have ticked the checkbox "Key pair information" under Certificate assistant. But push notification tutorials do not show it as checked. Should I ticke that checkbox? Should I create separate CSR for each app ?

Comment: @Vinod you're super brave, if your first application ever should use APNS. But really, this question is out of scope of this thread. Create another question, if you're having difficulties with APNS.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem appears in production (with your application on the appStore), it's very likely because you created/enabled the APNS production mode of your application **AFTER** having created the distribution profile.

In this case, no other option but to submit again with a correct certificate...

Rule of thumb: **ALWAYS** enable/create production certificate for your application **BEFORE** creating the distribution profile.

You can use the method described by 'nduplessis' (see below) to manually check if you application will run notification once approved.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 14 ?**

For those who faced with inability to get token, and double checked all the things mentioned above, and developed on iOS 14, and if you have non-english app title, go to **Project - Target - Product Name and replace name by $(TARGET_NAME).**

I spent entire week on this bug.

Once again: if your app receives token on iOS12, but can not on iOS14, get rid of non-latin chars in names. They say, including entitlements, but as for me, I've managed to make it work and with cyrillic entitlements. To change Product name was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen the push notification dialog in your app? If you dismiss the dialog it takes 24 hours to reshow. Check this by setting the time on your iPhone ahead by 2 days and see if it shows.

Also have you implemented the delegate methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
```

Try putting an NSLog(@"") in the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError and see it is is getting in there?

Also you require an App Id that is setup for Push notification and you need to have generated the Push notification certificates to send the messages.

Comment: yes,I have these methods. And also, I have app id with push notification services enabled.

Comment: I am getting the NSlog output for the method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" not for others . Now I am getting the error Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x1657c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

Comment: Check you are building against the correct provisioning file. Sounds like the problem to me. You would have had to create a provisioning file against the app Id with push notifications.

Comment: Should I create separate CSR for each iphone app ?

Comment: @Vinod No, one CSR is enough

Answer (score 0):

You can only register it with a provisioning profile having an app id with push notification services enabled.please Check those steps also.This a good tutorial for starting push notification http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Comment: I have set push notification services under my app id.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Capabilities** -> **Push Notifications**. If **there are errors** then try out this solution!

If **Xcode version was changed** from 7 to 8 then try out this solution!

Xcode 7 copies the aps-environment entitlement from your provisioning profile. Turning on push notifications on Xcode 8 adds the entitlement both to your provisioning profile and the entitlements file.

Try adding the aps-environment entitlement to your app's entitlements file, or switch the notification capability off and on again.